# Vertx: toWebSocket() with router fails in 3.9.16

Tags: java, groovy, websocket, vert.x

After downgrading Vertx from `4.x` to `3.9.16` the code:

```
class AvaHostVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
  @Override
  void start( Promise startPromise ) throws Exception {
    Router router = Router.router vertx
    new WebsocketHandler( router )
    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler router listen 7777, startPromise
  }
}

class WebsocketHandler implements Handler<AsyncResult<ServerWebSocket>> {
  WebsocketHandler( Router router ) {
    router.route '/ws' handler{ it.request().toWebSocket this }
  }
  
  @Override
  void handle( AsyncResult<ServerWebSocket> swsRes ) {
    if( swsRes.failed() ){
      log.error 'onWSConnect failed', swsRes.cause()
      return
    }

    ServerWebSocket sws = swsRes.result()
    // blah...
    sws.accept()
  }
}
```

stopped working, throwing the exception:

```
11:55:06.716 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] ERROR my.controller.WebsocketHandler - onWSConnect failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: null
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerConnection.createWebSocket(Http1xServerConnection.java:275)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerRequestImpl.upgrade(HttpServerRequestImpl.java:420)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.HttpServerRequestWrapper.upgrade(HttpServerRequestWrapper.java:313)
    at io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerRequest.toWebSocket(HttpServerRequest.java:386)
    at io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerRequest$toWebSocket.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
    at my.controller.WebsocketHandler$_closure1.doCall(WebsocketHandler.groovy:24)
```

This is the code in Http1xServerConnection where the ISE is thrown:

```
  ServerWebSocketImpl createWebSocket(HttpServerRequestImpl request) {
    if (ws != null) {
      return ws;
    }
    if (!(request.nettyRequest() instanceof FullHttpRequest)) {
      throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
```

The option with

```
vertx.createHttpServer().webSocketHandler wsHandler listen 8888
```

works just fine.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?